# Intuition for the commutation of the pullback and the exterior derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, pullback, exterior-derivative

I know that there are already several questions to this topic but I haven‘t seen a satisfactory answer. Deriving that the pullback and the exterior derivative commute is no problem but I want to know what is the (geometric) intuition behind that.

Comment: Pullback (or equivalently the expression of forms in coordinates) is defined to encode the change of variables formula. And the exterior derivative is the correct generalization of the 1D derivative that makes Stokes' theorem (the relevant generalization of fundamental theorem of calculus) work, as in @Charles' answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about Stokes' Theorem?
$$
\int_M dF^* \omega = \int_{\partial M} F^*\omega = \int_{F(\partial M)} \omega
$$
On the other hand
$$
\int_M F^* d\omega = \int_{F(M)} d\omega = \int_{\partial F(M)} \omega
$$
Is it easier to accept that integrating over $F(\partial M)$ is the same as integrating over $\partial F(M)$? I would argue it's easier to imagine what is going on geometrically, especially if we work with the chain complex version of Stokes' Theorem.

Comment: So it includes in a certain sense the invariance under diffeomorphisms?

Comment: The statement above doesn't require that $F$ is a diffeomorphism, only that it is smooth. It's more a statement that the boundary operator and smooth maps somehow commute. Again, this is made precise (and is practically a definition) in the context of chain complexes.